# How to deal with C++ non-const value errors?

Tags: c++

I'm getting some errors (which are shown below) I'm not exactly sure what is causing these errors. I looked through my teachers example code and I can't find anything that I'm doing that is causing this error.

I've also tried searching up the error and adjusting the code but have gotten nothing. I would appreciate some assistance with where I'm going wrong. Thank you!

```
// error
Rational.cpp:60:10: error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘Rational&’ to an rvalue of type ‘Rational’
return Rational(num, den);
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

// in Rational.h
Rational add(const Rational &r) const;

// in Rational.cpp
Rational Rational::add(const Rational &r) const
{
    int num = (numerator * r.denominator) + (denominator * r.numerator);
    int den = denominator * r.denominator; 

    return Rational(num, den);
}
```

p.s. I'm doing intro to C++, so I would appreciate simpler terms and explanations!

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Please post the errors as *text*.  The image is difficult to read.

Comment: You have `add` as a *free standing function*, not declared within a class, nor a namespace.  The `Rational::` indicates that the function should be in a class or namespace.

Answer (score 4):

The constructor is defined as `Rational::Rational(Rational&)` when it should take a `const` reference. You cannot bind a temporary to a non-const reference, and `add` returns a temporary. To use that temporary to initialize a newly-constructed rational, the constructor needs to take a non-const reference.

Comment: Thank you so much!
I now understand what I did wrong.

Comment: Or an rvalue reference